# Adding new Vocabulary after node being Updated

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I tried to add new vocabulary After Add/create a node for certain type..'`account`'

```
if ($node->type == 'account') {
  $nid   = $node->nid;
  $title = $node->title;
  $voc_title  = 'branches_' .$nid;
  $vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($title);

 if (!is_object($vocabulary)) {
   $vocabulary = new stdClass();
   $vocabulary->name = $title;
   $vocabulary->machine_name = $voc_title;
   taxonomy_vocabulary_save($vocabulary);
   node_save($account);
  }
}
```

How to add Vocabulary when Add/create a node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using the right hook, but you have some mistakes in your code.

In order to get the node title, you just need to do `$title = $node->title;`, the `node_load()` function expects a node ID, and not a title.

I don't understand where the `$nid` variable comes from. If you want the node ID, you need to do `$nid = $node->nid;`

The taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load() function will return FALSE if it can't the vocabulary, so you can use `if (!$vocabulary) {}`

Finally, you don't need to save your node at the end, because you are not changing anything on it.

**Final code**

```
if ($node->type == 'account') {
  // Don't know if you already have the full $node on the hook you are using
  $account = node_load($node->nid); 

  $title = $node->title;
  $name = 'branches_' . $node->nid;

  $vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($name);
  if (!$vocabulary) {
    $vocabulary = new stdClass();
    $vocabulary->name = $title;
    $vocabulary->machine_name = $name;
    taxonomy_vocabulary_save($vocabulary);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Well, I just see your answer, I clearly don't understand why you have a "field_account" on your node because your are calling your node `$account` ?

Comment: while i answerd i copied the whole code :) but it already work.. thank you for replay.. i Have field_account .. i use it to display NID after saving node..

Comment: your field_account is equal to the node id, I don't think it's necessary :)